# Can't login to Unity Hub Flatpak

Tags: login, firefox, flatpak, unity, kde-neon

I am trying to login to Unity Hub but it is not working.

When I open Unity hub I get the welcome page that prompts me to log in. When I click on the login button a web page is opened to log in (firefox is my default browser).

When I log in I get the prompt to allow the page to open a link using unity hub. When I click *allow* the page is blank and nothing happens on the unity hub app.

I am running KDE Neon 5.27.